# Delete rows from 3d array with zeros

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am working with images using OpenCV. The end image gives output with black and red pixels. For further processing I only want non-black pixels to be processed. If I check the data in NumPy it is seen as 3d array. How can I keep only non-zero rows; Below is the code;

[numpy.ndarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Giit.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like

```
array = np.array([[0, 10, 20], [20, 30, 40]])
array = array[array > 0]
```

This code drops your zeros.

Comment: That creates a 1d array, but I need to keep the dimension and just remove rows with 0 values ([0, 0, 0] must be removed. Below is the input;
[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [217, 125,  24],
        [255, 134,   0],
        [255, 182,  67],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],

Comment: then use np.reshape like here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html